# Stimulus controller action firing twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm new to StimulusJS, I just want to show the post content appended after other posts when the user adds a new post. Everything seems to work but the post is appended two times so it looks like the form was submitted twice.

```
  <div data-controller="posts">
     <div data-target="posts.add">
     </div>
     <!-- this is from a rails partial but it's all inside the data-controller -->
     <%= form_with scope: :post, url: posts_path, method: 'post', data: { action: "post#addBody" } do |form| %>
     <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form-control", data: { target: "posts.body"} %>
     <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

The actual controller:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["body", "add"]

  addBody() {
    let content = this.bodyTarget.value;
    this.addTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `<div>${content}</div>`);
  }
}
```

I know this works because it shows the post on the page when the form submits, but the function is called again and the post appears two times.  I've tried this with `debugger` and it seems like something internal in Stimulus is calling `addBody()` a second time?

As context this is what the posts_controller is doing:

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.post.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.json {head :ok}
      else
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in my `application.js` file.  I had:

```
const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context("../controllers", true, /\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))

import "controllers"
```

I don't know how the line: `import "controllers"` got there or what I thought it did but after removing it things are only firing once.

Answer (score 0):

So I know that by default, a form should listen for the `submit` event so you don't need to include the event name (See [here for event shorthands](https://stimulusjs.org/reference/actions#event-shorthand)) but I wonder if because it is a form with `remote: true` then it is also listening to the `ajax:success` event. If you try changing your data action to only listen for the `ajax:success` event does that solve it?

```
data: { action: "ajax:success->post#addBody" }
```

P.S I know this is a kind of speculative answer so might warrant a comment rather than an answer, but I do not have the reputation points to make a comment.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  So I tried a few things I thought I'd add the posts controller action for some context here, the response at the moment is super barebones but from what I have read it constitutes a successful response.  
I've tried adding `ajax:success->` to the data action, also tried with and without adding `remote: true` to the form.  No luck yet, still firing two times.